# Solving a set of equations with 4 unique variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is in the title. Is it possible to solve this system of equations?

$$a+c=160$$
$$c+d=140$$
$$a+b=130$$
$$b+d=110$$

I have tried to solve this to no avail. I have tried adding all of the equations with the same variables. This yields $2a+b+c=290$ and $c+b+2d=250$. Subtracting this gives $2a-2d=40$. I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Comment: This system of equations does not have a unique solution in (a,b,c,d) meaning that there are infinitely many. If a is a given number however then the rest can be calculated.

Comment: How do you know this?

Comment: if you take $d$ as the independent variable, you get $$ a = 20 + d, \; b = 110 - d, \; c = 140 - d. $$ Any $d$ works

Comment: Well I solved for c in terms of a using the first equation; then d in terms of a  with the second equation since we now have c; then b in terms of a with the third equation; we now have b, c and d in terms of a. The fourth equation is supposed to leave an equation in a with only one solution, but we find that everything cancels and the fourth equation is always satisfied, meaning that any value of a produces a valid solution.

Comment: Sniped by Will. Dang

Comment: Ah! That makes sense. Thank you Will and Faraz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a matrix equation of the form $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$, this looks like:
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \ 0 \ 1 \ 0 \\ 0 \ 0 \ 1 \ 1 \\ 1 \ 1 \ 0 \ 0 \\ 0 \ 1 \ 0 \ 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}160 \\ 140 \\ 130 \\ 110 \end{bmatrix}$$
The coefficient matrix $\mathbf{A}$ does not have an inverse, $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$, so there is no unique solution.

In general, since you have four linear equations each consisting of two variables, you could choose any $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ to satisfy the system.

If a system has $n$ linear equations, each of which having $m$ variables, then a unique solution only exists if $n = m$.

Comment: This makes sense, but how do you show that matrix A does not have an inverse?

Comment: $\det(\mathbf{A}) = 0$, so it is not invertible.